# How can I enable CDI with Jersey Test Framework?

Tags: unit-testing, jersey, testng, cdi, weld

I found [How can I inject a data source dependency into a RESTful web service with Jersey (Test Framework)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892349/330457) but I think I'm gonna ask a little bit different question.

This is a follow-up question of [@PostConstruct of abstract ancestors are not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29787068/330457)

I wrote a JAX-RS library and I'm trying to unit-test with [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

I seems HK2 injects properly. But I found some of my life cycle interceptor method annotated with `@PostConstruct` or `@PreDestroy` aren't invoked (or only some invoked).

```java
public class MyResource {

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed() { // not invoked
    }

    @Inject
    private Some some; // injection works.
}
```

How can I enable CDI with Jersey Test Framework? What kind of artifacts do I have to depend on?

Here is my current dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

I added following additional dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now Weld takes over HK2, I think. I don't know what `jersey-cdi1x-ban-custom-hk2-binding` is for. Anyway, I can use standard annotations from `javax.enterprise:cdi-api`.

```java
public class MyProducer {

    @Produces @Some
    public MyType produceSome() {}

    public void disposeSome(@Disposes @Some MyType instance) {}
}
```

And an initialisation code for Weld added.

```java
@Override
protected Application configure() {

    // this method works somewhat weirdly.
    // local variables including logger
    // is null in here
    // I have to start (and join) a thread
    // which initializes Weld and adds a shutdown hook

    final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        final Weld weld = new Weld();
        weld.initialize();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
            new Thread(() -> weld.shutdown()));
    });
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (final InterruptedException ie) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ie);
    }

    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig
        = new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);

    resourceConfig.register(MyProducer.class);

    return resourceConfig;
}
```

Every points get injected and all lifecycle methods are invoked. Yay!!!

---

I don't understand why I tried to use a thread in the first place.

```java
@Override
protected Application configure() {

    final Weld weld = new Weld();
    weld.initialize();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> weld.shutdown()));

    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig
        = new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);

    resourceConfig.register(MyProducer.class);

    return resourceConfig;
}
```

---

Since I use `JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerClassTest` I failed, at least with TestNG, to work with `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` because `configure()` method is invoked (indirectly) from the constructor.

I think I can use `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` for initializing/shutting-down Weld if I switch to `JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerMethodTest`.

---

`jersey-cdi1x` is a transitive dependency of the `jersey-weld2-se` so it can be omitted.

Comment: Just curious, have you simply tried `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotated methods to initialize and shutdown weld? Since this is a test class, it seems appropriate

Comment: @peeskillet I found `configure()` is, apparently, invoked indirectly from the constructor of `JerseyTest` class. That's why event `logger` is not useable in that method.

Comment: What I meant is that JUnit tests offer the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations that you can place on arbitrary static methods in your test class. The former will be called before the tests start and the latter after. Instead of the threading, I was simply wondering if it would work to have a static Weld field, start it in the before method, and shut it down in the after method.

Comment: @peeskillet I, unfortunately, use TestNG. I tried using static field and `org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass`. And it seems even `@BeforeClass` applies after instantiation. I'm not sure JUnit works differently.